# Can i link c# and html normally

Tags: c#, html

Hello every1 I am both new to this site and html so i wanna ask Can i do something like that

```
<link href="index.cs">
```

then use functions If possible how ??

I want to use functions that i declare in my c sharp file fro a button
like i dont know

```
<button id="button-test" onclick="helloworld()">click</button>
```

and i ll have a function in c sharp named helloworld like

```
void helloworld()
{
    return;
}
```

Thnx for ur answers

Comment: that's not how it works.

Comment: How can i do something like that

Comment: you should use Javascript. take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick)

Comment: well i am not good at js and i dont like it

Comment: Then you should work with Asp.Net and C#.

Comment: well, js has no alternative for client side. you may try [ASP.NET WebForms](https://www.asp.net/web-forms)

Comment: Have a look at https://www.asp.net/

Comment: i know about asp.net but for now I prefer to use html

Comment: then you have to use JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript functions or use asp.net.

You can call the function in controller class using ajax like this

```
$("#buttonId").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Controller/MethodName/{parameter}"
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use ajax and connect  to c# controller via ajax

Visit this link:
[AJAX Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp)!

Comment: It is highly recommended to bring your solution here, rather then giving a link-based answer. Links get broken.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using Blazor or Blazor WASM:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor

You can use C# client side.